# is a question about a specif form of a Korean word on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Let's say I want to ask a question about a specif Korean word used in a specific sentence, for example,

> 다음 대화를 잘 듣고 여자가 이어서 할 행동으로 알맞은 것은 고르십시오

Here the word 이어서 is formed from the root 잇다 and I want to know what happened to the ㅅ and what are the rules for converting 잇다 to 이어서. Are such questions on topic for the [korean](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/korean) tag here in Linguistics? I have gone through some of the questions but non seem to be specif to a particular word or grammar structure like this. Is this type of question on topic? There is a [Korean Language and Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language-and-usage?referrer=_bGLWL4a0nyN5qIsOP5VxA2) proposal in Area51  but until it get's created this site and the [korean](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/korean) tag seems to be closest place related to anything about Korean language in the SE network.

Would this and similar question be on topic here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't think it would be on-topic here. However, if your question pertains to [historical-linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-linguistics) or [cross-linguistic](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-linguistic), it might still be considered on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to state the question as a more general one that in principle relates to languages, in general. You may need to provide a bit of background (I would suggest also transliterating from Hangul to IPA), such as translating the words and providing a morphological analysis. This seems to have something to do with so-called *s*-irregular verbs, so you might be asking for a linguistic analysis of such verbs.